# how to "Resize" category filter in google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I have developed a web application using Google UIApp class, which has a Dashboard with pie charts with a category filter.

Problem is how the resize the category DropDown, because I have more than 50 items in the list and the names are more than 35 characters which is why they are overlapped from the drop down pane.

Note that it is not the normal UI list box, the list box generated with "Charts.newCategoryFilter()"

Please let me know for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about a ListBox?

[Google Documentation - UI List Box](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/list-box)

### Set Width:

[Google Documentation - UI List Box - Set Width](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/list-box#setWidth(String))

### Set Height:

[Set Height](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/list-box#setHeight(String))

Comment: No it is not the normal UI list box, the list box generated with "Charts.newCategoryFilter()".